# Apache HttpClient throws Remote host closed connection during handshake exception when trying to download file

Tags: java, ssl, curl, groovy, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a url where a file is available for download via http. If I hit that url with a curl the file downloads without issues. But if I try in code with Apache HttpClient, it gives an exception. Here is the code...

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("https://www2.mycompany.com/internet/cats/productfeed.nsf/xmlproductfeed?openview")
def responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(method)
```

The exception is

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
```

Could it be the https or the www2 in the url?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, then why does it work through curl, does that provide a certificate to the server?

Comment: Maybe this is the problem of setting `System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");`

Comment: I think this is due to using of TLS. I'm not sure because I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the URL through HTTPS, this is a TLS connection. You need to set up your client to use SSL/TLS.

Here is an example, rewrite to HttpGet, but this should be easy:

```
// Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,
            new String[] { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" }, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

    String userCredentials = username + ":" + password;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));

    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    localContext.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
```

Comment: With source code of createEasySSLContext() method it would be more useful answer. Except that the solution works great.